Runtime Error when calling the Report function of a class from another function
I have a problem which I don't understand why it is happening.
I need to display an Error message using the self.report function of a class. This works when it is called directly from the class but fails with a Runtime Error when called from an update function.
I rewrote the problem in a very simple sample code:
import bpy

x = 20

class Another_OT_Class(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "another.class_"
    bl_label = "Do_Something"

    def execute(self, context):
        if x < 10:
            print("Whatever")            
        else:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, 'This is the error message I want to display')        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def updVariants(self, context):
    if context.window_manager.Variants.variant_sel == 'Var1':
        bpy.ops.another.class_('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    elif context.window_manager.Variants.variant_sel == 'Var2':
        bpy.ops.another.class_('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

class Variants(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    variant_sel: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name='variant_sel',
        items=[
            ('Var1', 'First Variant', '', '', 0),
            ('Var2', 'Second Variant', '', '', 1),
        ],
        update=updVariants,
        default='Var1'
    ) 

class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_test"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Class Direct Call")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("another.class_",text=r"Push the button")
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Enum Property")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.window_manager.Variants, 'variant_sel', expand=True)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Variants)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Another_OT_Class)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.Variants = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Variants)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Variants)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Another_OT_Class)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.Variants
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Pressing the "Push the Button" button produces the required error message but pressing one of the Variants buttons, results in a Runtime Error:
Error: This is the error message I want to display
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/_BLENDER/Test/SCRIPT_Error_Msg_Test.blend/ui_panel_simple.py", line 20, in updVariants
  File "/usr/share/blender/4.1/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 107, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw, C_exec, C_undo)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Error: This is the error message I want to display

File "/_BLENDER/Test/SCRIPT_Error_Msg_Test.blend/ui_panel_simple.py", line 16, in updVariants

This doesn't make sense to me. Why can't I call the report function from a Class from another function?
It is also strange that the Error Message get's written to the console but not showing on the interface.

I don't know why you need the update function at all. You click either of the buttons for First/Second Variant it sets the variant property in the scene. The update function is not doing anything. Calling the other operator there is what's causing the error. As far as I can tell removing the updVariants function and the line for update in the EnumProperty makes the whole script run as intended.

As I wrote, this is just a small example to show the problem. In my Add-on I'm using a button combinations like the variants here (a switch selector of multiple choices) which is the easiest way to achieve such a selector. This relies on an update function and of course in the Add-on there are far more code behind it.

The report function of operators need to be run at special times.
Display the report when the custom button is clicked
import bpy

x = 20

class Report(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.report"
    bl_label = "Report"

    message: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    report_type: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="WARNING")

    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        try:
            self.report({self.report_type}, self.message)
            return {'FINISHED'}
        except:
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

def updVariants(self, context):
    bpy.ops.wm.report(message="You press a button.")


class Variants(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    variant_sel: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name='variant_sel',
        items=[
            ('Var1', 'First Variant', '', '', 0),
            ('Var2', 'Second Variant', '', '', 1),
        ],
        update=updVariants,
        default='Var1'
    ) 

class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_test"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Class Direct Call")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("another.class_",text=r"Push the button")
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Enum Property")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.window_manager.Variants, 'variant_sel', expand=True)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Variants)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Report)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.Variants = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Variants)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Variants)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Report)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.Variants
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Maybe I abstracted too much... Let's assume Another_OT_Class is doing some important things (comparing X in the sample code represents these important functions) and based on this calculations it might need to throw an error.  Some input is coming through the variant selector.  In your code you replaced my class with a pure report class. (But you still reference it in the panel). The blender classes have their own report function but they only work when called directly. Are you suggesting to write a report function in my Another_OT_Class besides the other functions?

In your case, you can do some jobs in class Another_OT_Class,  if you want to report something, return {'RUNNING_MODAL'} like the class Report.

Or check the x value in def updVariants to decide if reporting is required

Just for the sake of completeness, here is the complete working code:
import bpy

x = 20

class Report(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.report"
    bl_label = "Report"

    message: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    report_type: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="ERROR")

    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        try:
            self.report({self.report_type}, self.message)
            return {'FINISHED'}
        except:
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

class Another_OT_Class(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "another.class_"
    bl_label = "Do_Something"

    def execute(self, context):
        if x < 10:
            print("Whatever")            
        else:
            bpy.ops.wm.report(message="This is the error message I want to display")
            #self.report({'ERROR'}, 'This is the error message I want to display')        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def updVariants(self, context):
    if context.window_manager.Variants.variant_sel == 'Var1':
        bpy.ops.another.class_('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    elif context.window_manager.Variants.variant_sel == 'Var2':
        bpy.ops.another.class_('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

class Variants(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    variant_sel: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name='variant_sel',
        items=[
            ('Var1', 'First Variant', '', '', 0),
            ('Var2', 'Second Variant', '', '', 1),
        ],
        update=updVariants,
        default='Var1'
    ) 

class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_test"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Class Direct Call")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("another.class_",text=r"Push the button")
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Enum Property")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.window_manager.Variants, 'variant_sel', expand=True)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Variants)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Another_OT_Class)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Report)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.Variants = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Variants)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Variants)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Another_OT_Class)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Report)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.Variants
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

AS X Y suggested, I have to use my own Report class as the Blender built in  Class Report is throwing an error if it is called from another Class via an update function. (I would still like to know why is there a difference... Still don't make sense to me.)
With the suggested report function, the Error Message get's displayed regardless how it is called. Thanks!
